# mysqld constantly shutdown when trying to upgrade from '80033' to '80034'

Tags: mysql, upgrade

I left my ghost website running for a week on an ubuntu22.04 droplet on digitalocean and came back seeing mysql.service always in the status of "Server upgrade in progress".

```
root@ghostonubuntu2204-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo3-01:~# systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Wed 2023-08-23 22:55:08 UTC; 1min 43s ago
    Process: 15825 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 15833 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server upgrade in progress"
      Tasks: 28 (limit: 1100)
     Memory: 670.6M
        CPU: 1min 431ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─15833 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Aug 23 22:55:08 ghostonubuntu2204-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo3-01 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 23 22:55:08 ghostonubuntu2204-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo3-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 1min 1.013s CPU tim>
Aug 23 22:55:08 ghostonubuntu2204-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo3-01 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
```

I checked the error log and it indicates that mysql server is trying to upgrade from '80033' to '80034' but seems to fail over and over again.

```
root@ghostonubuntu2204-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo3-01:~# tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log
2023-08-23T22:53:15.741426Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-08-23T22:53:40.579981Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80033' to '80034' started.
2023-08-23T22:55:07.392287Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'ALTER TABLE user MODIFY ssl_type enum('','ANY','X509', 'SPECIFIED') NOT NULL; ' failed with error code = 3664, error message = 'Failed to delete SDI 'mysql.user' in tablespace 'mysql'.'.
2023-08-23T22:55:07.400274Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013380] [Server] Failed to upgrade server.
2023-08-23T22:55:07.401543Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-08-23T22:55:08.356084Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2023-08-23T22:55:08.886770Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 15833
2023-08-23T22:55:08.894543Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-08-23T22:55:11.720480Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-08-23T22:55:35.193655Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80033' to '80034' started.
```

The version of mysql is 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

I tried `systemctl restart mysql.service` but nothing changes.

I also tried to [uninstall mysql](https://dev.to/kinyungu_denis/how-to-uninstall-mysql-server-from-ubuntu-2204-1k9j) and install it again, but this error persists.

Any idea how I might be able to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with my Ghost blog a couple of days ago :(

First of all, I had to enable OS swap because my MySQL daemon was being killed by OOM killer time to time - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04
My current guess is that this issue was triggered by an interrupted update.

Anyway, the next step was to stop mysql service and run upgrade manually (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-what-is-upgraded.html):

```
systemctl stop mysql


mkdir /var/run/mysqld/
chmod -R 777 /var/run/mysqld/

/usr/sbin/mysqld --upgrade=MINIMAL
/usr/sbin/mysqld --upgrade=FORCE
```

This resolved the 'ALTER TABLE user MODIFY ssl_type enum' issue for me.

Note, I had to open another Digital Ocean console to kill mysqld that I started manually.

```
ps auxf | grep mysqld
kill -9 XXX
```

Without that you cannot start systemd's MySQL: `Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11`

```
systemctl start mysql
systemctl status mysql
```

Comment: I'm also having this issue with my ghost installation. I tried the above steps but still getting "Server upgrade in progress" when I restart mysql. Also when I kill the process using another console and run the ps command again in the original console another process is automatically started for mysql.

Comment: I'm also having a similar issue. I created the swap file of 2G on my digitalocean droplet, and all I get is `Server upgrade from '80033' to '80034' started` followed by: `xecution of server-side SQL statement 'EXECUTE stmt; ' failed with error code = 1205, error message = 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction'.` in the logs...

Comment: I fixed this by doing `--upgrade=minimal` instead :)